# AngularJS: read response data from server

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a problem which should be wasy to solve, but I just cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I receive `data` through an `$http` request.

```
alert(data)
```

gives me `object object`

```
alert(data.response)
```

gives me `{"id":"123456","post_id":"12345"}`

```
alert (data.response.id)
```

gives me `undefined`

My question: I want to get the ID. **Why does the last expression give me undefined and not the ID?** Do I have to transform the data in some way?

I am thankful for any hints!

Comment: It means that `data.response` is a string, not an Object. Otherwise similarly to `alert(data)` you would have got `[object Object]`.

Comment: Your response is probably a string. You'll need to turn it into JSON first. Call the function angular.fromJson on $scope.data.response then you can call the id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your data.response is a string.
You use `angular.fromJson` to convert it to object ie :

```
$scope.temp = angular.fromJson($scope.data.response);
```

please see working demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope){
 $scope.data = {
 response:'{"id":"123456","post_id":"12345"}'
 };
  
  alert($scope.data);
  alert($scope.data.response);
  
   alert($scope.data.response.id);
  
  $scope.temp = angular.fromJson($scope.data.response);
  
  alert($scope.temp.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

      </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer and perfectly explained!

Answer (score 1):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('list_employeesController', function($scope, $http) {
  // email = $scope.email;
  // psw = $scope.psw;
  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/employees",
    params: {}

  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
      // a string, or an object, carrying the response from the server.
      $scope.myRes = response.data;
      $scope.statuscode = response.status;

    }, function myError(response) {
      $scope.myRes = response.statusText;
  });
});
```

Simply Here myRes has the response data to this request.

And we can display it in HTML file using expression syntax in angular

```
 <h2> Result : {{myRes}} </h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('student_Controller', function($scope, $http) {

  $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/employees",
  }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

      $scope.res= response.data;
      $scope.statuscode = response.status;

    }, function myError(response) {
      console.log("response--"+response);
  });
});
```